# Writing out a new entry in PowerApps using Power BI

Tags: powerbi, powerapps

In PowerBIIntegration mode, what formula to use when writing out a new entry (row) into my Excel Table on OneDrive.

I have published my Power BI Report to Power BI Online - I have added 5 fields from 2 tables in my input Excel file -> I have created a NewForm screen in PowerApps starting from Power BI -> my PowerBIIntegration data table contains the fields that populate the dropdowns in the NewForm -> now I want to write a NewForm entry into my 3rd table in my Excel file called Assignments - I cannot use the SubmitForm control. what formula do I use? My fields are called function, job etc..

Comment: In summary you want to crate a record in Excel from PowerApps, Is that so??

Answer (score 0):

I got the patch function to work as follows -

Patch(Assignments, Defaults(Assignments), {JOB: Dropdown_Job.Selected.Result})

and this is writing my data successfully back into Excel.